# Vue get sender element with other parameter

Tags: vue.js

In my VueJs app i have a html part like this

```
<MyAwesomeComponent @change="onChangeValue" class="component" />
```

and in the method i have

```
onChangeValue: function (event)
{
//here i can access succesfully to event.sender
}
```

the question is: how is possibile to have custom parameter inside onChangeValue function?

i've tried to add parameter but i only get undefined and null value

any suggestion?

Comment: please explain why you need it, sounds like your not using $emit correctly

Comment: because the component is a general pourpose one, in this case i need for validation and show error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onChangeValue function, you will create an event like `$emit('nameOfEvent',yourDataToPass)` . nameOfEvent will be usefull to get your event in the upper component like `@nameOfEvent="yourFunction($event)"` . And yourDataToPass will be one of your data in DATA(){mydata;} like `this.mydata`

Answer (score 0):

In your child component, you can call `$emit('change',customArg)`

Comment: you mean 'MyAwesomeComponent' this one? is part of kendo-ui component

Comment: Yes, child component emits event, parent component gets notified. If MyAwesomeComponent is an already existing component, you can wrap it with another wrapper component to make it work the way need.